# How to query Kafka topic for records in a partition with timestamp inside interval?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've got a Kafka topic (version 1.0.0) with time-series data. I want to find all records with a specific key and where the record timestamp is within a given time interval.

My current approach is as follows:

1. Create a KafkaConsumer with `enable.auto.commit` set to false (thus avoiding committing offset when polling)
2. Find the partition that holds the key I'm looking for
3. Assign that partition to the KafkaConsumer
4. Through `offsetsForTimes`, find the offset closest to the start of the time interval
5. `seek` the KafkaConsumer to start reading at that offset
6. Do `poll` in a loop, accumulating all records with matching key until a record is returned with a timestamp later than the end of the time interval

This kind of works. Here are some issues:

- the `poll` function sometimes returns empty lists before the end is reached.
- if the end of the interval is right now, the polling won't stop until a record in the future is written to the topic.
- is it safe to reuse the same consumer group id on multiple threads?

Is there a better way to query for historical records?